# Import strings from Neo4j json dump

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Say I populate a Neo4j graph as follows:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Andy', title: 'Developer'})
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Betty', title: 'Developer'})
```

And I dump the contents Neo4j to a json file as follows:

```
call apoc.export.json.all("dump.json",{useTypes:true})
```

I would like to import the contents of that json file into a second database instance. I am aware I can import with:

```
call apoc.import.json("dump.json")
```

But in my situation I will have the contents of the file in memory (it is guaranteed to not be very large) and cannot load the file from the filesystem. How can I import those lines into the second instance? I don't see a way to do this with apoc.import. Perhaps the way to do this to somehow use `apoc.convert.fromJsonList`? Am I missing a straightforward way to import these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use APOC export and stream the results so that you can either [import it via cypher-shell](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/cypher/#export-cypher-cypher-shell), or if you do not have access to it, [using the Neo4j browser](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/cypher/#export-cypher-neo4j-browser).

Example:

To import via cypher-shell -

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all(null, {
    batchSize: 5,
    streamStatements: true,
    format: "cypher-shell",
    useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 5}
})
YIELD nodes, relationships, properties, cypherStatements
RETURN nodes, relationships, properties, cypherStatements;
```

To import via Neo4j browser -

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all(null, {
    format: "plain",
    useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20}
})
YIELD file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize
RETURN file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize;
```

Comment: Thanks! `apoc.export.cypher.all` got me on the right track - I was able to execute all the unwind statements in that file and achieve exactly what I wanted.